# Table scroll when changing tabs

Tags: swift, tabbar

I'm wanting to scroll a table view to the top when someone clicks the tab bar icon.
My tab bar has 4 tabs, the table is on index 0.

I can currently get it to scroll to the top correctly, but I only want it to do it when on index 0, not when returning from the other items.

Currently I have

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex

    if tabBarIndex == 0 {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

What I want is if you are on index 0, then scroll back to the top, if you are going to 0 from another tab, then leave the scroll as it is.

Comment: if I understood you , you want each tap to store its scrolling position but at index 0 you want to. scroll to top , if it's like that you can use a dictionary  to store (visibleIndexPaths.last).row  and when you select a tap get its stored value and scroll to it

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It dawned on me you can do the whole process on *shouldSelect*

You need to know which tab was previously selected. One way to do this is to move the logic to "tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController)"

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // first condition checks the selected tab is the current view controller
    // second verifies you are not coming from another tab
    if viewController == self && viewController == tabBarController.selectedViewController { 
         tableView?.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This isn't working, the code in the if isn't being ran. The current setup of the tabs is tab bar controller -> navigation controller -> table view

Comment: View controllers have a property called _navigationController_. You can change the first condition to "viewController == navigationController" so it works with your setup.
Your if condition would then be  
`if viewController == navigationController && viewController == tabBarController.selectedViewController`